# Email Reply to address

Tags: php, email

I'm having a problem with an email reply to address.
For some reason the MIME type is showing in the reply address.

Here are the headers

```
$headers = 'From: The Client <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: info@mydomain.com';
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

When I get the mail, if I hit reply, in the address field I get this:

```
"1.0" <info@mydomain.commime-version:>
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't work it out.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `\r\n`:

```
$headers = "From: The Client <".$emailTo.">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: info@mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Comment: D'oh!
Thought it was something simple. Been driving me mad.
Thanks you VERY much, both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed `\r\n` after Reply-To.

```
$headers = 'From: The Client <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";
```